# Metoerjs : How do I run node inspector while connecting to a remote mongodb

Tags: meteor, node-inspector

I am trying to debug some meteorjs server code. I connect to an instance of mongodb by using the following command line, which works perfectly.

MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb meteor

So, I tried the following command to connect to the node inspector and the mongodb simultaneously, which I think is not working because now the queries that I run against the db are coming back empty.

MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb; NODE_OPTIONS='--debug-brk’ meteor

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: `mydb` vs `Mudb`, couldn't it be just a typo error ?

Comment: It was typo. Now corrected.

Answer (score 0):

What if you do

```
MONGO_URL='mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb' NODE_OPTIONS='--debug-brk’ meteor
```

Hope this helps!